# Excel - How to get contents of LeftHeader?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to do a find-and-replace on pagesetup leftheader. Caveat is that I need to know the contents of the LeftHeader in order to replace it using Substitute. For example, the LeftHeader could contain:

Sheet 1 - Updated - 1/12/19 
Printed on 6/3/19

I would do a find-and-replace on 1/12/19 and 6/3/19 using below example code:

```
Sub FnR_HF()    
    Dim sWhat As String, sReplacment As String
    Const csTITLE As String = "Find and Replace"

    sWhat = InputBox("Replace what", csTITLE)
    If Len(sWhat) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    sReplacment = InputBox("With what", csTITLE)

    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        ' Substitute Header/Footer values
        .LeftHeader = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute( _
                      .LeftHeader, sWhat, sReplacment)
    End With
End Sub
```

The above doesn't allow me to retrieve the contents of the LeftHeader. Can anyone help?

Comment: This code works, I just tried it. Check that your left header isn't empty

Answer (score 0):

Rather than find/replace, why not just rename it?

It will generate a popup box with your existing header showing, and you can type over it with whatever you want the new header to be. Seems easier?

```
Sub MakeAHeader()

    Dim aText As String, WS As Worksheet
    Set WS = ActiveSheet

    aText = InputBox("What do you want the header to be?", "Make Yo Header", WS.PageSetup.LeftHeader)

    WS.PageSetup.LeftHeader = aText

    MsgBox "This is your header: " & WS.PageSetup.LeftHeader

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Sub FnR_HF()
Dim sWhat As String, sReplacment As String, sHeader As String
Const csTITLE As String = "Find and Replace"

sHeader = ActiveSheet.PageSetup.LeftHeader

sWhat = InputBox("Replace what", sHeader)
If Len(sWhat) = 0 Then Exit Sub
sReplacment = InputBox("With What", csTITLE)

sHeader = Replace(sHeader, sWhat, sReplacment)

ActiveSheet.PageSetup.LeftHeader = sHeader
End Sub
```